# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a select tag inside my FormArray and i have fetched option for that select using http from the api. I have following error help me.

> CashPluckingLeafComponent.html:44 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ
>   supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
>   supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

[image]
[image]

```
 <div formArrayName="leaf_grade">
                    <div *ngFor="let grades of cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls; let i=index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="i">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Leaf Grade {{i + 1}}</label>
                                <select name="grade" formControlName="grade" class="form-control" id="grade">

                                    <option *ngFor='let lg of grades' [value]="lg.name">{{ lg.name }}</option>
                                </select>
                                <small *ngIf="!cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls[i].controls.grade.valid && cplForm.controls.leaf-grade.controls[i].controls.grade.touched">
                                    Leaf Grade is required
                                </small>
                                <div>
                                    <span *ngIf="cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls.length > 1" class="remove-form-control">
                                        <a (click)="removeGradeData(i)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**grades** contain from console.log(grades)

(2) [Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2

Comment: You're passing an object to `*ngFor` but it only supports an array. I don't see a way to help from here, because it's not possible to derive from the provided information what exactly is passed to `*ngFor`.

Comment: add the data format what you are trying to loop. The error explains you are trying to loop objects or something else instead of `Array`

Comment: console.log(grades) outputs : (2) [Object, Object] 0: Object 1: Object  length: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have overlapping names. The array you want to iterate has the **same** name as each form object in your form array that you are iterating in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let grades of cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls; let i=index">
```

So now in your template Angular is trying to iterate the **form group** `grades` instead of your **array** of `grades`. You need to rename either, for example the iteration of the form array...

```
<div *ngFor="let gradesGroup of cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls; let i=index">
```

Comment: oops! such a small mistake wasted my hour searching the solution. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: validation inside formArray is not working. can you help me with it. `<small *ngIf="!cplForm.controls.leaf_grade.controls[i].controls.grade.valid>Invalid Input</small>`

Comment: That looks totally correct to me. By the way, you can shorten that with whatever name you chose for iteration, so if you chose `gradesGroup` you can use `gradesGroup.controls.grade.valid`. But as said, your code looks correct, could you recreate the issue in a plunker and I'll be happy to take a look :)